# how to enable hybrid mode in graphhopper for traffic data

Tags: graphhopper

how to enable hybrid mode for graphhopper 0.9 version. in the config file, what all we need to enable/disable/change

my intention is to use traffic data using the link
[graphhopper-traffic-data-integration](https://github.com/karussell/graphhopper-traffic-data-integration/)

i am not able make it work, when i feed the data using curl, i get below error

{
  "message" : "Not found"
}

i tried changing the prepare.ch.weightings=hybrid but i get error

```
now web. JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1000m -Xms1000m -server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: weighting null not supported
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.createWeighting(GraphHopper.java:908)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.initCHAlgoFactoryDecorator(GraphHopper.java:798)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.load(GraphHopper.java:738)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importOrLoad(GraphHopper.java:617)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GraphHopperModule$3.start(GraphHopperModule.java:182)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.start(GHServer.java:118)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.start(GHServer.java:62)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.main(GHServer.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the hybrid mode you can disable the speed mode:

prepare.ch.weightings=no

and set the default `fastest` weighting for hybrid:

prepare.lm.weightings=fastest

See [the documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.9/docs/core/landmarks.md)

Comment: with the above setting , the graphhopper is starting thanks, now i am trying to feed data using curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @traffic-home.json http://localhost:8989/datafeed                   i get the below error { "message" : "Not found" }