# Graphhopper with hybrid mode enabled throws IllegalStateException

Tags: graphhopper

I'm trying to start Graphhopper in hybrid mode using the latest code from its git repo.

The config file, per its comments and documentation (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426814/how-to-enable-hybrid-mode-in-graphhopper-for-traffic-data)) has:

```
prepare.ch.weightings: no
prepare.lm.weightings: fastest
```

I build it with `docker build -t tgraphhopper:lastest .` and then I start one container with `docker run --name tgraphhopper -v ./data:/data -p 8989:8989 tgraphhopper:latest`

The error which appear in logs is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configured graph.ch.weightings: [] is
>   not equal to loaded [fastest|car]
>           at com.graphhopper.storage.GraphHopperStorage.loadExisting(GraphHopperStorage.java:254)
>           at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.load(GraphHopper.java:781)
>           at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importOrLoad(GraphHopper.java:637)
>           at com.graphhopper.http.GraphHopperManaged.start(GraphHopperManaged.java:71)
>           at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
>           at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
>           at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
>           at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
>           at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
>           at com.graphhopper.http.GraphHopperApplication.main(GraphHopperApplication.java:33)

What am I missing in tyring to start the Graphhopper in hybrid mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the (potentially) created cache folder for the graph in /data

(So, if you have `area-latest.osm.pbf` the folder is named `area-latest.osm-gh`)